# Continuity and Closed Intervals with an equal function

Tags: real-analysis

PRoblem: If $f$ is a continuous function whose domain includes a closed interval [$a$,$b$] and $p$ $\in$ [$a$,$b$], then the set of all numbers $x$ $\in$ [$a$,$b$] such that $f(x)$ = $f(p)$, is a closed point set.

PRoof:

Let $f$ be a continuous function whose domain includes [$a$,$b$]

Then if $S$ is any open interval containing the number $f(x)$, then there is an open interval $T$ containing the number $x$ such that if $t$ $\in$ $T$, and $t$ is in the domain of $f$, then $f(t)$ $\in$ $S$ (our class' defintion of continuous)

Let $p$ $\in$ [$a$,$b$]

Let $T$ = [$a$,$b$]

Then $a$ $\lt$ $p$ $\lt$ b and $p$ $\in$ $T$

I am unsure how incorporate this defintion to prove this theorem.

Comment: Consider the set $S=\{x\mid x\in[a, b], f(x) =f(p) \} $ then $S$ is non-empty and let $s$ be a limit point of $S$. Show that $f(s) =f(p) $.

Comment: In most of your questions I see the problem statement and definition of terms and then you expect a solution here. It is better to show your approach to the problem and what issues you are facing. Based on this information you can get more helpful answers. If for every problem you are unsure of "how to proceed" then it is time to revisit the definitions and concepts and seriously question yourself whether you really understand them.

Comment: I think that's my problem, I don't understand them thoroughly. I come here to get insight about certain approaches to take.

Comment: You can ask exactly what you don't understand. Without understanding the concepts these problem solving techniques are of no use. Just to encourage you, the problems you have posted so far are trivial if you understand the concepts. You can always ask questions about elaboration of the concepts and about examples and counter-examples to enhance your understanding. And most importantly contrary to the popular belief the subject of real analysis is not more edifficult than other branches of math.

Comment: I've really appreciated all your help these last couple of weeks, Paramanand!

Answer (score 1):

If $x_{n}\in S:=\{x\in[a,b]: f(x)=f(p)\}$ is such that $x_{n}\rightarrow q$. Then $q\in[a,b]$ at first. Now $f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(q)$ by continuity. But $f(x_{n})=f(p)$ for each $n$, so $f(q)=f(p)$, so $q\in S$.

Comment: Minor typo. You need to replace $p$ by $f(p) $ based on notation used in question.

Comment: Where does the q come from?

Comment: That is an assumption. Essentially, if we want to prove that $S\subseteq{\bf{R}}$ is closed, by an equivalent definition, we let $x_{n}\in S$ be such that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, and then try to argue that $x\in S$.